# passing argument with InvokeCommandAction MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress-wpf

I want to disable the cell/Column based on some business logic. I am using `ShowingEditor` event and `ShowingEditorEventArgs` to cancel it. Passing `ShowingEditorEventArgs` would be excellent.I am able to pass the full grid as an argument. using below code. But i just want to pass `ShowingEditorEventArgs`  of selected cell.May be some relative resource binding help me out here.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" >
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView Name="view"  ShowingEditor="view_ShowingEditor">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ShowingEditor">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowingEditorCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}}" />
```

...
Note:

1. I can't use **MVVM light**(*GalaSoft*).
2. interactions are not giving me CallMethodAction.

   ```
   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
   <ei:CallMethodAction
   ```
3. I don't want to pass the binded property of `ViewModel`(e.g. `SelectedItem`)
4. Using **DevExpress** GridControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the DevExpress MVVM Framework, where you can pass event args to the view model as a parameter:

```
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="ShowingEditor" Command="{Binding ShowingEditorCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Or even convert the EventArgs object before passing it to your command using a converter specified by the EventArgsConverter property.

Take a look at the [EventToCommand](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17369) article to learn more.

P.S. If you cannot use DevExpress MVVM Framework for some reason, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565484/how-can-i-pass-the-event-argument-to-a-command-using-triggers) describes how to implement a custom TriggerAction passing event args to a command manually.