# DataGrid CellEditEnding event to command. How to pass in DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs 'e'? MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So i've got my command working, except for the fact that I'm not getting the `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` 'e' passed down to me... this is my xaml in the datagrid

```
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MainWindowViewModel.ObjDataGrid_CellEditEnding}"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And my test command

```
    private ICommand objDataGridCellEditEnding;
    public ICommand ObjDataGrid_CellEditEnding
    {
        get
        {
            if (objDataGridCellEditEnding== null)
            {
                objDataGridCellEditEnding= new RelayCommand(CellEditEndingTest);
            }
            return objDataGridCellEditEnding;
        }
    }

    private void CellEditEndingTest(object param)
    {

    }
```

`param` is always null.... and I don't know why...

Any help would be appreciated...

Where `e` is needed

```
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            TextBox cellTextEdit = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
```

Comment: have you tried specifing the `CommandParameter` xaml attribute?

Comment: hey Daniel, I thought that but I wasn't sure what would go in...

Comment: what ever you want it to be!

Comment: well, I want it to be what the usual event passes in... so how would I do that?

Comment: i.e. DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e

Comment: with the mvvm pattern you shouldn't care about that. what specific data do you need from `e`?

Comment: hey daniel, see edit,.

Comment: i'm doing a bulk edit. and i need to know the edit action and the editing element

Comment: nvm... I found this which works :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565484/how-can-i-pass-the-event-argument-to-a-command-using-triggers